# how to compare two images stored in a file using opencv

Tags: c++, c, opencv, machine-learning

my hard disk contain 3380 frames extracted from 2 minutes video.

1. i want to group similar frames and from each group one/two frame are taken as a header of the group which represent the whole group of frames.
2. i tried with histogram comparison also but **histogram** gives graphical representation only,

i am doing summarization of videos

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Read a video file from file

    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromAVI("C:\\Users\\Pavilion\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\video\\optical illusions.avi");
    int loop = 0;
    IplImage* frame = NULL;
    Mat matframe;
    Mat img_hsv, img_rgb;
    char fname[20];
    do
    {
        // capture frames from video

        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        matframe = cv::cvarrToMat(frame);

        // create a window to show frames
        cvNamedWindow("video_frame", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

        // Display images in a window
        cvShowImage("video_frame", frame);
        sprintf(fname, "C:\\Users\\Pavilion\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\video\\video\\frames\\frame%d.jpg", loop);

        // write images to a folder
        imwrite(fname, matframe);
        // Convert RGB to HSV

        cvtColor(img_rgb, img_hsv, CV_RGB2HSV);

        loop++;
        cvWaitKey(10);
    } while (frame != NULL);
    return 0;
    /*
    // read and process frames from file
    char name[50];
    int i = 0;
    Mat output_image;

    while (1){

    sprintf(name, "frame%d.jpg", i);

    //Load the image
    Mat input_image = imread(name, 1);
    if (!input_image.data) break;

    //Image RGB to Grayscale
    cvtColor(input_image, output_image, CV_RGB2GRAY);

    //Applying Gaussian
    GaussianBlur(output_image, output_image, Size(21.0, 21.0), 50.0);

    //applying adaptive threshold
    adaptiveThreshold(output_image, output_image, 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, THRESH_BINARY_INV, 111, -20);

    sprintf(name, "frame%d-bin.jpg", i);

    //save the image
    imwrite(name, output_image);

    i++;


    }
    */

}
```

can someone help me in this , i am new to opencv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group similar images using feature detection. If you get enough `matches` from `frame1` and `frame2`, they should be similar.

Comment: thank you for your answer David. can you send code for feature detection ,i googled it but can't find the answer.

Comment: Tutorial from OpenCV site: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html

Comment: hello davidgsola   i tried feature matching with flann.  it gave me the good result for similar frames, but when i compared distinct frames it gave me more matches.here is output which i got  1. for frames 203 and 245 i got 45 matches which are similar frames 2. for frames 204 and 2045 i got 213 matches which are different frames. based on this result it cannot group similar frames. can you help me to find the solution for it